# Run functions in another javascript context in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I would like to run JavaScript code via evaluate in a specific JavaScript Context.

[image]

The code I want to run is `Scrivito.getClass("Page").create({ title: "Hello world!" });`

I try the following code but it throws the error that `Scrivito` is not defined.

```
const frame = page.frames()[1];
const result = await frame.evaluate("Scrivito.getClass(\"Page\").create({ title: \"Hello world!\" })");
```

When I copy the code `Scrivito.getClass("Page").create({ title: "Hello world!" });` in the web developer tools of Puppeteer Chromium with the right context then it runs without problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you so sure `.frames()[1]` is the right frame?

Comment: There are only two frames. I guess the top one is at `[0]`. If I choose the `[0]` in Puppeteer, I get the same error as in Chrome when I choose the top context.